# Swift: Saving a JSON variable from a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm stumped with the following problem: I am calling a JSON file, parsing it into data strings, creating MapBox annotation points. All works well.
What I can't figure out is how to save a variable for the currently tapped point's annotation data (for example the title).

I have created a variable `stationNameString` which is populated by `point.title`. The problem is that since it is in a for loop, all the resulting `destViewCont.LabelText` in the segued window show the last in a series of titles from the JSON (logically, because the loop has stopped), but each `addAnnotation(point)` is different (which is correct). Since the loop has stopped and I'm further in the code, I'm unable to grab the correct title of the point being tapped.

How can I get the title from a certain annotation to be passed on to the segued modal?

```
class MapController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
@IBOutlet var mapView: MGLMapView!

var stationURL = "http://..."

var stationNameString = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let styleURL = NSURL(string: "...")
    let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: styleURL as URL?)
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    mapView.delegate = self

    // Set the map’s center coordinate and zoom level.
    mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), zoomLevel: 9, animated: true)
    view.addSubview(mapView)

    mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow

    Alamofire.request(stationURL).responseJSON { response in

        if response.result.value != nil {
            NSLog("Success")
            let stationJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            let allStations = stationJSON["Stations"]

            for (_, object) in allStations {
                let stationId = object["id"].stringValue
                let stationName = object["name"].stringValue
                let stationLat = object["lat"].stringValue
                let stationLng = object["lng"].stringValue
                let stationStreet = object["street"].stringValue
                let stationCity = object["city"].stringValue
                let stationPostcode = object["postcode"].stringValue

                if stationLat != "0.000000" && stationLat != "1.000000" {
                    let point = SubMGLAnnotation(
                        coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(stationLat!)!, longitude: Double(stationLng!)!),
                        title: stationName! + " (" + stationId! + ")",
                        subtitle: stationStreet! + ", " + stationCity! + " " + stationPostcode!
                    )

                    pointAnnotations.append(point)

                }

            }
            mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations)
        }
    }

}



func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, rightCalloutAccessoryViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView? {

    return UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotation: MGLAnnotation, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetail", sender: view)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destViewCont : StationController = segue.destination as! StationController

    destViewCont.LabelText = stationNameString

    if (segue.identifier == "toDetail" ) {
        print("Segue toDetail")

    }

}
```

Edit: Added subclass

```
class SubMGLAnnotation: NSObject, MGLAnnotation {

var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?

var image: UIImage?
var reuseIdentifier: String?

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: String?) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
}
}
```

Edit: Changed prepare for segue, but this causes app to crash.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "toDetail" ) {
        print("Segue toDetail")

        let theDestination : StationController = segue.destination as! StationController
        theDestination.LabelText = (sender as! SubMGLAnnotation).title!

    }

}
```

Could not cast value of type 'MGLMapView' (0x1006a7000) to 'App.SubMGLAnnotation'

Comment: Not related, but retrieving `stationJSON["Stations"][i]` 7 times in each loop is pretty inefficient.

Comment: You should probably enumerate directly the elements of the `allStations` array rather than going by index.

Comment: on a side note, Always perform UI updates on main thread...!!!!

Comment: I tried making a function 'getAlamo' in the main thread and calling it from viewDidLoad. Problem is that then 'self.mapView.addAnnotation' doesn't do anything, the reason being unknown to me.

Comment: You should create your own subclass of MGLAnnotation and add properties as required. Then create instances of this class and add them to your map as you are doing now. Then you can simply pass the selected annotation to the next view controller

Comment: @Paulw11: I have created the subclass and annotations are working in the main view. How would I go about passing the annotation and showing the title? (edited question)

Comment: @vadian, jcaron : Fixed, thanks for the tip!